# How can I remove this gap here?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-family: oswald light;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3c78d8;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: oswald light;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3c78d8;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

img {
  background-color: #3c78d8;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 25px 624px 25px 624px;
}
```

```html
<div>header1</div>
<img src="2898chevronlogo.svg">
<h2>header2</h2>
```

Using internal css, there exists a gap in between img and h2 that I want to get rid of.

Here is an image of the gap:

[image]

Comment: right click the area and click "inspect" then look for the "computed value" of the margin and/or padding

Comment: you can do like this h2 {margin:0;}

Comment: img {
        background-color:#3c78d8;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 25%;
        padding: 25px 624px 0px 624px;
    }

Comment: H2 has default margin values. Add `margin:0` to `h2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to add `margin-top: 0px;` to your h2 declaration.

As code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>2898 The Flying Hedgehogs</title>
<style>
    body {
        background-color:lightgray;
    }
    div  {text-align:center;
        font-size:75px;
        font-family:oswald light;
        color:white;
        background-color:#3c78d8;
    }
    h2 {
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: oswald light;
        color:white;
        background-color: #3c78d8;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    img {
        background-color:#3c78d8;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 25%;
        padding: 25px 624px 25px 624px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>header1</div>
<img src="2898chevronlogo.svg">
<h2>header2</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When developing new pages, you should clear the default styles by adding the following to your css.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This will fix your issue:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-family: oswald light;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3c78d8;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: oswald light;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3c78d8;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

img {
  background-color: #3c78d8;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 25px 624px 25px 624px;
}
```

```html
<div>header1</div>
  <img src="2898chevronlogo.svg">
<h2>header2</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-top: 0;` to styles for h2 tag.

```
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: oswald light;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3c78d8;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `margin-top:0` to the `h2`'s styling should do the trick

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>2898 The Flying Hedgehogs</title>
<style>
    body {
        background-color:lightgray;
    }
    div  {text-align:center;
        font-size:75px;
        font-family:oswald light;
        color:white;
        background-color:#3c78d8;
    }
    h2 {
        margin-top:0; /*add this */
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: oswald light;
        color:white;
        background-color: #3c78d8;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    img {
        background-color:#3c78d8;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 25%;
        padding: 25px 624px 25px 624px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>header1</div>
<img src="2898chevronlogo.svg">
<h2>header2</h2>
</body>
</html>
```